# Scrapy does not respect LIFO

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I use Scrapy 1.5.1

My Goal is to go through entire chain of requests for each variable before moving to the next variable. For some reason Scrapy takes 2 variables, then sends 2 requests, then takes another 2 variables and so on.

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
```

Here is my code sample:

```
def parsed ( self, response):
    # inspect_response(response, self)
    search = response.meta['search']

    for idx, i in enumerate(response.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1']/tr")[1:]):

        __EVENTARGUMENT = 'Select${}'.format(idx)

        data = {

                      '__EVENTARGUMENT': __EVENTARGUMENT,

                  }

        yield scrapy.Request(response.url, method = 'POST', headers = self.headers, body = urlencode(data),callback = self.res_before_get,meta = {'search' : search}, dont_filter = True)     


def res_before_get ( self, response):
    # inspect_response(response, self)
    url = 'http://www.moj-yemen.net/Search_detels.aspx'
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.results, dont_filter = True)
```

My desired behavior is:
1 value from `Parse` is sent to `res_before_get` and then i do smth with it.
then another values from `Parse` is sent to `res_before_get` and so on.

```
Post
Get
Post
Get
```

But currently Scrapy takes 2 values from `Parse` and adds them to queue , then sends 2 requests from `res_before_get`. Thus im getting duplicate results.

```
Post
Post
Get
Get
```

What do I miss?

P.S.
This is asp.net site. Its logic is as follows:

> 1. makes POST request with search payload.
> 2. Make GET request to get actual data.
> 3. Both request share the same sessionID

Thats why it is important to preserve the order.

At the moment im getting POST1 and POST2. And since the sessionID is associated with POST2, both GET1 and GET2 return the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy works asynchronously, so you cannot expect it to respect the order of your loops or anything.

If you need it to work sequentially, you'll have to accommodate the callbacks to work like that, for example:

```
def parse1(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(..., callback=self.parse2, meta={...(necessary information)...})


def parse2(self, response):
    ...
    if (necessary information):
        yield Request(..., 
             callback=self.parse2, 
             meta={...(remaining necessary information)...},
        )
```